# How to sample a certain number of random columns from each row in a matrix

Tags: r

I want to sample a certain number of random columns from each row in a matrix. For example, I have a matrix A and I want to randomly select 2 out of 4 columns from each row and the selected column index for each row can be different. Do you know how to do it in R? Thanks!

```
A=matrix(0, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could loop over the `col`s of the data by row with `apply` (`MARGIN = 1`) and `sample` with `size = 2`

```
t( apply(col(A), 1, FUN = sample, size = 2))
```

---

Or using `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
dapply(col(A), MARGIN = 1, FUN = sample, size = 2)
```

#### Update

Based on the comments, may be

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(A)), function(i) {
     x <- A[i, ]
     ci <- seq_along(x)
     sn <- sample(ci, 2)
     matrix(x[sn], nrow = 1, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(i, sn))
})
```

-output

```
[[1]]
  1 3
1 0 0

[[2]]
  4 1
2 0 0

[[3]]
  4 2
3 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks! When I use "t( apply(col(A), 1, FUN = sample, size = 2))", the cell values in the matrix I got are the selected column numbers. Is there a way to keep the original row index of A in the new matrix and have the selected columns numbers shown in the column index instead of the cells. And the cells should be the original cell values in A.